# Word document appears to have unwanted dotted lines

Tags: microsoft-word

When I open or create a new Word document, the paragraph is sorrounded as a dotted line and the images don't display well. It's very difficult edit like this. But when I open Read Mode the document displays correctly. I show you an image in the Print Layout mode:

[image]

I don't know if I have some active option in the settings. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Does this occur regardless of which template you use? (So instead of just opening a new word document, use the 'new document' option to select another format and see if it occurs there as well.)

Comment: it ocurres everywhere with a new document or an old one. It seems that it is not a problem with the templates.